# Starting clickhouse-server in docker fails with error from Poco

Tags: docker, clickhouse

I'm trying to start clickhouse-server using the official docker container. I pulled the latest one, tried starting it and receive the following error:

**Poco::Exception. Code: 1000, e.code() = 0, e.displayText() = Not found: logger, e.what() = Not found**

I'm trying to do this on Mac with High Sierra, suspecting this might have something to do with the issue. I'm running the server like that:

`docker run --name some-clickhouse-server --ulimit nofile=262144:262144 -v /Users/dmitrysmirnov/clickhouse/config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml yandex/clickhouse-server`

Config:

```
<yandex>
    <listen_host>0.0.0.0</listen_host>
    <listen_try>1</listen_try>

    <!--
    <logger>
        <level>trace</level>
        <console>1</console>
    </logger>
    -->
</yandex>
```

Any suggestions / debug ideas are welcome, thank you!

Comment: Howdy, comrade, got the same error while running `clickhouse-copier` with local zookeeper in docker and remote clickhouse nodes. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately didn't solve it, resorted to running the whole thing on linux machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it is not a problem of ClickHouse itself. You have an error in `docker run` command. The `-v` option is here for setting the volume, not specific file. So, literally, you create a directory with path `/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml/` which is brakes Clickhouse warming up.

Instead of this, I would like to suggest you put your config.xml in directory, and link that volume with config.d folder inside ClickHouse image. `config.d`, as well as `users.d`, and other `.d` are considered to use exactly this way. So:

```
docker run --name clickhouse-server -v `(pwd)`/dir/:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d yandex/clickhouse-server
```

Also, a good idea to check other options of [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/). BTW: I found `-d` option is a must have, because detached container makes my terminal be more useful.

Comment: Man, You saved my nerves) Thanks!